# getting decodable error when trying to use decodable struct in another as array

Tags: swift, decodable

I'm getting in decodable error: does not conform to Decodable ...

for:

```
struct Packages : Decodable {
let id: Int
let name: String
let idService: Int
let nationality: String
let totalPrice: Int
let visitsPerWeek: Int
let pricePerVisit: Int
let excludedDays: String
let excludedShifts: String
let excludedDates: String
let extraVisits: Int
let dateEnabled: String
let dateDisabled: String
let allowedFrom: String
let allowedTo: String
let visitType: String
let createdAt: String?
let updatedAt: String?
}
struct Nationalities : Decodable{
let id: Int
let name: String
let createdAt: String?
let updatedAt: String?
}
struct Services : Decodable{
let id: Int
let name, description: String
let createdAt: String?
let updatedAt: String?
}
```

i"m using it here like:

```
struct Root2 : Decodable {
let services : [Services]
let nationalities : [Nationality]
let packages : [Packages]
}
```

Here i'm getting:

> Root2 does not conform to Decodable

Why? and how to solve it?

Comment: does `Services` and `Nationality` conform to `Decodable` too ?

Comment: @CZ54 yeah .. just updated my post

Comment: `Nationalities` ? or `Nationality` ?

Comment: @CZ54 OMG!!!!! I can't believe it!!! yes thank you this was the error x_x

Comment: @CZ54 thank you so much!

Comment: same time answer and same time comment :D

Comment: @PPL yeah thank you too! i will accept your answer

Comment: @mrs.tat Hope you will do it :)

Comment: did you got an error like Nationality type not found or defined.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan no its actually defined as another class .. that's why i didn't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this,

```
struct Root2 : Decodable {
    let services : [Services]
    let nationalities : [Nationalities]
    let packages : [Packages]
}
```

See the difference between `Nationality` & `Nationalities`